# Ponto final dentro de parênteses

Tags: pontuação

Em alguns textos, já vi ponto final dentro de parênteses, mais especificamente antes do fechamento deles. Por exemplo:

> Estou falando daquele ponto de vista (embora não pareça bom aos olhos dos outros.)

A vida toda usei com o ponto final fora:

> Estou falando daquele ponto de vista (embora não pareça bom aos olhos dos outros).

Qual é o mais correto?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No teu exemplo o ponto final tem de ficar de fora. Das duas uma: ou os parênteses ficam dentro da frase, ou a frase fica dentro dos parênteses. Parênteses dentro da frase é o mais comum:

> Estou falando daquele ponto de vista (embora não pareça bom aos olhos dos outros).

Neste caso os parênteses encerram um à parte [(tecnicamente, um parêntese)](http://www.aulete.com.br/par%C3%AAntese) dentro da frase. Logo, ou os parênteses estão bem no meio da frase (como estes parênteses) ou estão encostados ao fim, mas fechando antes do ponto final (como estes). 
A outra possibilidade é o à parte ser uma frase completa, que começa e acaba, com o seu ponto final, dentro dos parênteses:

> Vamos hoje falar de verbos transitivos. (Os verbos intransitivos serão tratados noutra ocasião.) Os verbos transitivos podem ser diretos ou indiretos.

O que não pode acontecer é uma frase começar fora dos parênteses e acabar dentro deles (poder, pode mas está errado.)