# A vírgula vai antes, depois do parênteses, ou simplesmente não se usa vírgula com parênteses?

Tags: pontuação

Vou dar dois exemplos um tanto diferentes:

> - Depois de um instante João decidiu subir a colina (certamente a melhor saída a ser tomada), mas no tumulto da festa a escalada foi
>     adiada...
> - ...resultam em elementos de matriz zero (ver sessão 15.4), assim os únicos termos que contribuem...

Estes usos estão corretos? Existem regras para isso?

Comment: Martin, são exemplos distintos, porém ambos com o mesmo caso de uso (vírgula depois do parêntese final). Não ficaria mais claro se desses exemplos reais onde não há vírgulas, ou elas existem antes ou depois dos parênteses?

Comment: @gmauch Meu ponto é que não lembro de ter visto caso algum em que a vírgula vem antes do parênteses. Eu sempre uso depois, mas não conheço nenhuma regra que possa me dizer que estou certo.

Comment: Eu diria que a regra é depende do sentido da frase, mas se os parênteses abrem um comentário ou clarificação em relação à parte anterior da frase, como é mais comum, só faz sentido que a vírgula venha depois dos mesmos, para pausar ou separar em relação à segunda parte da frase.

Comment: Acho que a vírgula nos dois exemplos são desnecessários. Uma vírgula tem a ver com a pausa na frase e não com parênteses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra dizem na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* (Lisboa, 2014, p. 823) o seguinte:

> A posição dos parênteses com referência aos sinais pausais obedece à seguinte norma constante dos acordos ortográficos luso-brasileiros: «Quando uma pausa coincide com o início da construção parentética, o respetivo sinal de pontuação deve ficar depois dos parênteses; […]

Vejamos um exemplo. Comecemos com uma frase sem parênteses:

> Chico da Mouraria ensina que «esta vida são dois dias», aforismo repetido à exaustão pela sua legião de admiradores.

Se agora introduzirmos, na frase acima, o título da obra e página entre parênteses, a pontuação não se altera; se quisermos o parêntese junto à vírgula, terá de ser antes dela:

> Chico da Mouraria (*Memórias*, p. 987) ensina que «esta vida são dois dias», aforismo repetido à exaustão pela sua legião de admiradores.
>
> Chico da Mouraria ensina que «esta vida são dois dias» (*Memórias*, p. 987), aforismo repetido à exaustão pela sua legião de admiradores.

Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra contintuam:

> […] mas, estando a proposição ou frase inteira encerrada pelos parênteses, dentro deles se põe a competente notação».

Este assunto foi tratado [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/843/ponto-final-dentro-de-par%C3%AAnteses), mas eu deixo aqui um exemplo:

> Chico da Mouraria ensina que «esta vida são dois dias». (É provável que este Chico da Mouraria seja inteiramente fictício.) Este aforismo é repetido à exaustão pela sua legião de admiradores.