# Ponto final dentro ou fora das aspas?

Tags: gramática, pontuação

Nunca tinha parado para me perguntar isso, e me parece bem óbvia a resposta, porém queria saber se existe alguma diferença entre:

> “A vingança nunca é plena, mata a alma e a envenena.”

e

> “A vingança nunca é plena, mata a alma e a envenena”.

Quando devemos empregar um ou o outro caso?

Porque esses dias quando estava escrevendo uma citação, me pareceu meio sem sentido escrever:

> "xxxxxx.".

E ainda me parece ser o mesmo caso de:

> (xxxxx.).

Comment: Mas, Marcelo, nenhuma das opções que apresentas corresponde ao exemplo dado. Sugiro que mudes uma das opções para corresponder, ou que adiciones uma terceira opção à tua pergunta.

Comment: Sobre parênteses, podes ver [*Ponto final dentro de parênteses*](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/843/ponto-final-dentro-de-par%C3%AAnteses) e também [*Vírgula antes ou depois do parênteses*](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3483/a-v%C3%ADrgula-vai-antes-depois-do-par%C3%AAnteses-ou-simplesmente-n%C3%A3o-se-usa-v%C3%ADrgula-co?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Em Inglês se usa o ponto sempre dentro das aspas, o que sempre achei muito estranho...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inicio a resposta com exemplos:

**Citações, palavras irônicas ou enfatizadas, estrangeirismos:**

- Ele é um verdadeiro "expert".
- Você recebeu o meu "feedback"?
- Conforme dizia Descartes: "Penso, logo existo". (em citações  **."** também é aceito - vide regras abaixo)
- Ele disse "não".

**Transcrições:**

- "Mas a saudade é isto mesmo; é o passar e repassar das memórias antigas." (Machado de Assis, Dom Casmurro)
- "Há três espécies de mulheres neste mundo: a mulher que se admira, a mulher que se deseja e a mulher que se ama." (Almeida Garrett)
- "Quanto mais conheço os homens, mais estimo os animais." (Alexandre Herculano)

**EXPLICAÇÃO** - [**O uso da pontuação ao lado de aspas**](https://www.tjsc.jus.br/web/servidor/dicas-de-portugues/-/asset_publisher/0rjJEBzj2Oes/content/pontuacao-no-uso-das-aspas;jsessionid=D5E481211B8C53277B0EB120C95C276E.liferay-p2)

> - Se a citação inicia e encerra o parágrafo, o ponto final é colocado antes das aspas.

ex -  “Não vou admitir votos contra uma questão fechada do partido.”

> - Quando a citação não inicia, mas encerra o parágrafo, o ponto final fecha depois das aspas.

ex - Na opinião do senador, “é imperiosa a aprovação da reforma fiscal”.

Observação: se houver dois-pontos antes da citação e o trecho citado termina com ponto, a pontuação final pode ficar antes ou depois das aspas:

O ministro disse à comissão: “Se todos estão de acordo, apresentarei o relatório na próxima reunião”.

O ministro disse à comissão: “Se todos estão de acordo, apresentarei o relatório na próxima reunião.”

> - Quando há citação dentro da citação, usam-se aspas simples.

“O presidente da República garantiu ‘uma solução negociada para o conflito’, porém todos sabemos que ele é um demagogo.”

> - Quando a pausa coincide com o final da expressão ou sentença que se acha entre aspas, coloca-se o sinal de pontuação depois delas, se encerram uma parte da proposição.

“Este é o orçamento de que dispomos”, afirmou o líder do partido governista.

Comment: Em outras palavras: se o sinal de pontuação faz parte da citação, deve ir dentro das aspas. Caso contrário, fora das aspas.

Comment: Isto é muito análogo à pontuação com parênteses.

Comment: O link apodreceu. :(

Comment: @ANeves  É, acontece às vezes.  Já coloquei outro.

Answer (score -2):

Bem, até onde se tem conhecimento seriam fora das aspas, mas, se estiver citando algo de um autor, ou um trecho de livro, aí é dentro o ponto.

Comment: Olá Maria, tudo bem? O objetivo aqui é criar também um conteúdo com referências e explicações, não apenas um ponto de vista com falta de algum embasamento. Poderias melhorar a tua resposta levando em conta esses aspectos?

Comment: Oi Maria, por favor, não pense que nossa comunidade não é acolhedora - muito pelo contrário, ela ainda precisa crescer e novos contribuintes são muito valorizados. Os comentários negativos que suas respostas tiveram até agora têm como objetivo apenas guiar novos participantes e garantir que as regras do site (como as que exigem respostas autocontidas e embasadas/com referências) sejam respeitadas.