# Em que (boa) referência posso encontrar regras de pontuação relativas a citações?

Tags: português-brasileiro, pontuação

Refiro-me a regras que digam sobre um ponto final dentro de aspas ou fora de aspas.  Posso encontrar mil pessoas relatando as regras pela Internet, mas gostaria de referências robustas, especialmente em livros como gramáticas ou de estilo.

Comment: Creio que a tua pergunta não difere [desta que já existe](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/ponto-final-dentro-ou-fora-das-aspas). Se a pergunta e resposta que lá está não responde completamente à tua dúvida, reformula a tua pergunta para nós sabermos exatamente o que falta.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ponto final dentro ou fora das aspas?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3972/ponto-final-dentro-ou-fora-das-aspas)

Comment: @Jacinto, a pergunta é na verdade diferente porque estou em busca de referências.  A [resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3972) não cita nenhuma referência, exceto possivelmente um site (que inclusive gera 404 file not found no momento).  Estou em busca de referências acadêmicas, se possível.  Por exemplo, algum livro importante de estilo menciona essa regra?  (Se não houver um livro especificamente sobre português brasileiro, português português é uma boa alternativa.)  Muito obrigado por considerar a questão!

Comment: No meu tempo de faculdade, tinha as Regras da ABNT para trabalhos técnicos. Eu seguia esse padrão. Já procurou essa referência?

Comment: Pra algumas coisas eu tenho a norma.  Por exemplo, pra citações eu conheço a [NBR 10520](https://www.usjt.br/arq.urb/arquivos/nbr10520-original.pdf), mas ela parece só tratar de citações e não de aspas e pontuação também.  Talvez exista, mas ainda não a encontrei.  Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como a sua pergunta é muito específica, talvez você não encontre uma resposta única e abrangente em manuais de gramática ou estilística. Recomendo que, caso você seja acadêmico de uma universidade, siga as normas de sua instituição.

As regras de pontuação sobre citações em documentos são intuitivas. Basta analisar um exemplo de citação direta.

**Exemplo de citação direta**

> A teleconferência permite ao indivíduo participar de um encontro nacional ou regional sem a necessidade de deixar seu local de origem. Tipos comuns de teleconferência incluem o uso da televisão, telefone, e computador. Através de áudio-conferência, utilizando a companhia local de telefone, um sinal de áudio pode ser emitido em um salão de qualquer dimensão. (NICHOLS, 1993, p. 181).

Extraído da NBR 10520 (2002), o exemplo supracitado aponta a necessidade do ponto final no fim do enunciado e após a chamada. Aspas só são necessárias em citações diretas com até três linhas. Ver abaixo:

> “Não se mova, faça de conta que está morta.” (CLARAC; BONNIN, 1985, p. 72).

O ponto final deve aparecer antes das aspas e após a chamada.

Você pode encontrar pequenas divergências em manuais para elaboração de trabalhos acadêmicos que adotam as NBRs da ABNT. A saída mais fácil é seguir as convenções de sua instituição que, de qualquer maneira, sugerem um determinado uso da pontuação, mesmo intrincado.

**Referência**

ASSOCIAÇÃO BRASILEIRA DE NORMAS TÉCNICAS (ABNT). **NBR 10520**:
informação e documentação: citações em documentos: apresentação. Rio de
Janeiro, 2002.